# In Excel, "TRUE" is taken as boolean "TRUE" by default, which is failing my selenium code

Tags: selenium

In my excel Input -- one of cell Value is "true", by default Excel takes this as "TRUE"--boolean value.

I tried to handle this in my code, when this value is read, I am doing `.toString()`. Even this it fails.

Any workarounds please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please prepend `true` with single quote by that way you are forcing the cell to consider the as text.